# Evaluation of integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{(k+\frac{1}{2})^{n+2}} J_{0}(2k\sin\theta) \sin{(\tau\sqrt{k})}\mathrm{d}k$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

How to compute the integral that showed in the title. $J_0$ is the Bessel function. Parameters $\tau$ is a positive real number and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, n is a positive integer. Any help on it is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{(k+\frac{1}{2})^{n+2}} J_{0}(2k\sin\theta) \sin{(\tau\sqrt{k})}\mathrm{d}k
=
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2k^2}{(k^2+\frac{1}{2})^{n+2}} J_{0}(2k^2\sin\theta) \sin{(\tau k)}\mathrm{d}k
$$

Comment: Have you tried replacing $k$ with $x^2$ then applying the residue theorem?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio While $k=\pm i \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ are high order singularities. Can residue theorem solve it?

Comment: yes, as well as it is possible to compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$ with the residue theorem.

Comment: May I have the details when the Bessel functions included? Much appreciated.